# Inbound Firewall Rule Not Allowing Traffic When Program Specified

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall, netsh

I am trying to establish a firewall rule that allows incoming traffic to my application.  However, the rule does not appear to be allowing the traffic as desired.  I am using `netsh` to establish the rule, but when I specify the path to my program the rule appears to not allow the traffic as desired.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="My Application Rule" 
    program="C:\Program Files (x86)\MyComp\MyApp\MyApp.exe" dir=in action=allow
    protocol=TCP localport=7890-7894
```

When I do not specify the program the traffic is allowed, however, this is not desired because it'll allow traffic to any application listening on those ports.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="My Application Rule" dir=in
    action=allow protocol=TCP localport=7890-7894
```

Comment: Take note that if you are using GUI for this task, it's either `localport` or `program`, not both.

Comment: @Kitet I have used both the GUI and command line to add the desired rule with the same results each time.

Comment: So `MyApp.exe` is certainly not the right App. It could be a sub-process of `MyApp.exe`. What is `MyApp.exe` ? a real App or a custom dev ? You could check what happens with Wireshark.

Comment: @user2196728 `MyApp.exe` is a .NET application that I work on.  My end goal is to figure out what commands I need to run via the command line in the installer, so network traffic can reach the program without an administrator needing to configure the firewall manually.